# I hope vs. I wish

Tags: idiomatic-language

When someone starts a new endeavor, how can I give him my best wish?

> I wish you best luck in pursuing the Ph.D.
>
> I hope you best luck in pursuing the Ph.D.
>
> I wish everything would go smoothly for your research.

Is the subjunctive mood right?

> I hope everything will go smoothly for your research.

I am a bit confused here because of the following usage of wish:

> I wish the sun could rise from the West.

In this construction, the clause cannot be true but is wishful thinking. When I wish someone good luck, I hope I do not mean that it is wishful thinking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Hope* and *wish* are synonymous but have different root meanings and inferences, therefore they cannot be used interchangeably all the time.

I think the best way to distinguish them is that "a hope" is a *feeling*, whereas "a wish" is an *expression* of your hopes. In idiomatic use, the difference between the two has blurred a little, but traditionally, you *make* a wish while you *have* a hope.

Here is an example where they are interchangeable:

> I hope for good weather
>   I wish for good weather

In your example though, they are not interchangeable:

> I wish you best luck in pursuing the Ph.D.

This is fine and idiomatic.

> I hope you best luck in pursuing the Ph.D.

This is not idiomatically correct. It should be:

> I hope you *have good* luck in pursuing the Ph.D.

Your last example has a different idiomatic meaning:

> I wish everything would go smoothly for your research.

This would be taken as a *lament* - when we use "wish" about something that is already happening it suggests that we are wishing for a *reversal of fortune* or a *change in present conditions*. I would assume from this statement that things are *not* going smoothly at present.

A more idiomatic way to express a desire that things *continue to go well* would be:

> I *hope* your research continues to go smoothly.

OR

> I *wish* you well in your continued research.